# insert laravel log in logstash

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

i search tutorial of using logstash for logs in laravel and found it something like this:

first create a logstashLogger class :

```
class LogstashLogger {

/**
 * @param array $config
 * @return LoggerInterface
 */
public function __invoke(array $config): LoggerInterface
{
    $handler = new SocketHandler("udp://{$config['host']}:{$config['port']}");
    $handler->setFormatter(new LogstashFormatter(config('app.name')));

    return new Logger('logstash.main', [$handler]);
}

}
```

then i added logstash to channels in `logging.php` :

```
    'logstash' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via'    => \App\LogstashLogger::class,
        'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_PORT', 4718),
    ],
```

and i finally logged like this:

```
Log::channel('logstash')->debug('Logging to logstash');
```

and the question is where can i see the logs and what is the index ? it is confusing

logstash.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

Comment: The index is defined in your Logstash configuration. Is your Logstash instance running? Do you have something in the logs? Update your question with your logstash configuration.

Comment: @leandrojmp /etc/logstash/conf.d/elasticsearch-output.conf or filebeat.yml?

Comment: The `filebeat.yml` file is a Filebeat configuration, are you using Filebeat for collect logs as well? The code you shared is sending log directly to Logstash, so you need to share the Logstash configuration.

Comment: @leandrojmp content of `/etc/logstash/logstash.conf` added to post

Comment: @leandrojmp i want to send directly to logstash

Comment: Another question, do you have Elasticsearch and Kibana already installed an running? This is where you will see the logs.

Comment: @leandrojmp yes . i changed the to env('LOGSTASH_PORT', 5044) based on `logstash.conf` . but i got connection refused. port based on config file is 5044 . how can i get the correct port of logstash?

Answer (score 0):

Your logstash configuration only has a `beats` input on port `5044`, but your application is configured to send logs using `UDP` on port `4718`.

You need to have an UDP input listening on that port, you will also need to specify an indexname in your elasticsearch output.

A configuration to listen for logs from your application and send it to elasticsearch would be something like this:

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 4718
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "index-name-for-your-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Comment: not work yet ! not added any index to elasticsearch and so cant see any thing in my kibana panel. sorry could you guiding me for better choice udp or tcp ? im on my local laptop for test the log